# Issue with CURL POST request, getting curl_setopt() parameter warning

Tags: php, curl, post

Tried to send the post request with XML body using CURL but constantly getting following error,

```
Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given
```

I'm using following CURL request,

```
$ch = curl_init(POST_URL);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: $xml is the issue, what is it?

Comment: $xml is the valid XML string that I'm trying to post to the URL.

Comment: thats not what goes in the postfields http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the warning is referring to the `CURLOPT_MUTE` option. According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), `CURLOPT_MUTE` was removed in cURL 7.15.5:

> CURLOPT_MUTE   TRUE to be completely silent with regards to the cURL functions.
>   Removed in cURL 7.15.5 (You can use CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER instead)

When running your code (PHP 5.5.35, reporting all errors) I get a notice:

```
Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_MUTE - assumed 'CURLOPT_MUTE'
```

And then a warning:

```
Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given
```

So it seems that PHP interprets `CURLOPT_MUTE` as a string, hence the warning.

Comment: this suggests @Hem have a dangerous error_reporting level set in his development system's php.ini. which should be `error_reporting= E_ALL`.  but Hem has, at best, `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`, or possibly something even worse. he should fix that (ps, the undefined constant error was promoted from E_NOTICE in PHP5 to E_WARNING in PHP7)

Comment: @hanshenrik Yes, I used an old local server to test the code.